# Join each dynamically created checkbox array to its own comma separated list

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a form I am creating that has an initial form field with a group of check boxes:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <label class="radio control-label" style="text-align:left;">Sizes</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="728x90" name="sizes[]">728x90</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="300x250" name="sizes[]">300x250</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="320x50" name="sizes[]">320x50</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="300x600" name="sizes[]">300x600</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="510x60" name="sizes[]">510x60</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="Other" name="sizes[]">Other</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="sizes" name="join_sizes[]" size="70" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

I have additional jquery code that adds a duplicate of the above code when a button is clicked.

```
<input class="btn btn-success form-control add_field_button" type="button" value="+" />
```

An additional script is ran to join the values in to a hidden field "join_sizes[]".

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('input').on('click', function() {
        var values = [];
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        values.push($(this).parent().text());
        });
    $('[name="join_sizes[]"]').attr({value: values.join(', ')});
        });
    });
});
```

The issue I am having when checking my POST data is I get one field with `join_sizes[]` that is equal/duplicates to the selection made from the first group of boxes.

I assume I need to work with a key, but can't figure it out. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in this code,

1. Since you are working with dynamic elements need to use event delegation
2. When you check a checkbox, you need to set the value of the `join_size` element in the same `form-group

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'input[name="sizes[]"]', function() {
    var $group = $(this).closest('.form-group');

    $group.find('input[name="join_sizes[]"]').val(function() {
      return $group.find('input[name="sizes[]"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
      }).get().join();
    });
  });

  $('.add_field_button').click(function() {
    var $clone = $('.form-group').first().clone();
    $clone.find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false).end().find('input[name="join_sizes[]"]').val('');
    $clone.insertAfter('.form-group:last')
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form-group'>
  <label class="radio control-label" style="text-align:left;">Sizes</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="728x90" name="sizes[]">728x90</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="300x250" name="sizes[]">300x250</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="320x50" name="sizes[]">320x50</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="300x600" name="sizes[]">300x600</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="510x60" name="sizes[]">510x60</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="Other" name="sizes[]">Other</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="sizes" name="join_sizes[]" size="70" />
</div>


<input class="btn btn-success form-control add_field_button" type="button" value="+" />
```